# Is guice 4.0 backwards compatible with 3.x?

Tags: guice, guice-3

Is guice 4.0 backwards compatible with 3.x?
Cannot figure it out from the release-notes or FAQ...

If not, is there a list of compatibility issues somewhere?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I haven't any official source *but from my experience there isn't any compatibility issue.*

I use several guice features (bindings, provider, scopes...) and some extensions (assisted injection, multibindings, custom scopes).

I switched from guice 3.0 to guice 4.0-beta4 (then 4.0-beta5, 4.0) without any problem. My initial motivation was the java-8 support of the new version.

Comment: [Here](https://google.github.io/guice/api-docs/4.0/api-diffs/changes.html) is the full set of API changes between Guice 3 and 4.  Some of those are technically incompatible (methods added to interfaces) but most projects will continue working.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Gin then there is some compatibility issue with Guice 4. This is due to Gin depending on guice-assistedinject 3.0 which is incompatible with Guice 4.

I guess this mostly matters if you're using GWT.